# How to resolve a dependency extension within a Gradle build script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm using the `maven-publish` plugin in my `build.gradle`. For each of the `compile` dependencies, the `group`, `name` and `version` are used to generate the appropriate tags in the generated `pom.xml` file - and this works fine.

Here are the example dependencies I have:

```
dependencies {
  compile (
    [group: 'com.actionbarsherlock', name: 'actionbarsherlock', version: '4.4.0',  ext: 'aar'],
    [group: 'com.android.support',   name: 'support-v4',        version: '19.0.+']
  )}
```

Here is the publishing element I have:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    // A publication named 'mavenAndroid'
    mavenPublishLibrary(MavenPublication) {
      // Artifact using the aar from the build output
      artifact "${project.projectDir}/build/outputs/aar/${project.name}-${project.version}.aar"

      // Generate dependencies manually for POM
      pom.withXml {
        def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

        //Iterate over the compile dependencies, adding a <dependency> node for each
        configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
          def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
          dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
          dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
          dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)

          // This is what I'd want to do...
          if (it.ext != '') {
            dependencyNode.appendNode('type', it.ext)
          }
          // ...but this doesn't work!
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to be able to add the `ext` value (e.g. `aar`) to the `pom.xml` along with the `group`, `name` and `version`, something like what I have in the above snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I ask these questions when I've been struggling for hours, and then I always seem to answer myself soon after asking it!

I used the following to get the dependency extension, replacing the `if()` in the question:

```
it.getArtifacts().each {
  dependencyNode.appendNode('type', it.getExtension())
}
```